# jQuery insert div as certain index

Tags: jquery

Say I have this:

```
<div id="controller">
 <div id="first">1</div>
 <div id="second>2</div>
</div>
```

but say I wanted to insert a new div arbitrarily based on an index I supply.

Say I gave the index to insert of 0, the result should be:

```
<div id="controller">
  <div id="new">new</div>
  <div id="first">1</div>
  <div id="second">2</div>
</div>
```

and if I have an index to insert of 2 the result would be.

```
<div id="controller">
  <div id="first">1</div>
  <div id="second">2</div>
  <div id="new">new</div>
</div>
```

and if I give an index of 1 the result would be:

```
<div id="controller">
  <div id="first">1</div>
  <div id="new">new</div>
  <div id="second">2</div>
</div>
```

just forget that last example's format. The simple act of copying and pasting HTML code on this site is horrific enough to make me about scream and pull my hair out and I dont want to spend anymore time messing with it!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

As a function with a little better handling of 0:

```
function insertAtIndex(i) {
    if(i === 0) {
     $("#controller").prepend("<div>okay things</div>");        
     return;
    }


    $("#controller > div:nth-child(" + (i) + ")").after("<div>great things</div>");
}
```

EDIT: Added parenthesis in the nth-child selector to avoid NaN errors. @hofnarwillie

```js
function insertAtIndex(i) {
  if(i === 0) {
    $("#controller").prepend("<div>okay things</div>");        
    return;
  }


  $("#controller > div:nth-child(" + (i) + ")").after("<div>great things</div>");
}

window.doInsert = function(){
  insertAtIndex(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controller">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
</div>
<button onclick="doInsert()">Insert "great things" at index 2.</button>
```

Comment: You might wanna use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/), instead of [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) ;)

Comment: You should use `$("#controller > div:nth-child(" + i + ")").before("<div>great things</div>");` because otherwise the new element might get inserted multiple times, in childs of childs of `#controller`

Comment: This will fail silently for the second example. There is no element at position 2, therefore no element to insert before. Since you're already catching position 0 and handling it separately, this should work:
`$("#controller div:nth-child(" + i - 1 + ")").after("<div>great things</div>");`

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't `eq(i)` serve the same purpose as `nth-child(" + i - 1 + ")`?

Comment: need to turn `:nth-child(" + i - 1 + ")"` into `:nth-child(" + (i - 1) + ")"` otherwise you may get a NaN issue. Added the fix to the answer.

Comment: @AndyGaskell i noticed that the selector, nth-child, index starts from 1 in jQuery. So, i think it should be i instead of i - 1, right ?

Comment: Time saving tip: if you have other elements (H1, whatever) as siblings of the divs, nth-child counts those as well.. it actually ignores the div portion of the div:nth-child.  eq() does not behave this way... it honors the selector.

Comment: This code has a subtle bug - nth-child uses 1-based indexing, not 0. So if you attempt to insert at index 1 (the element will become the second element), then your selector should be `nth-child(1)` and your function should be `after`. This will use `nth-child(0)`, which will return no elements.

Answer (score 62):

I had a similar problem. Unfortunately none of the solutions worked for me. So I coded it this way:

```
jQuery.fn.insertAt = function(index, element) {
  var lastIndex = this.children().size();
  if (index < 0) {
    index = Math.max(0, lastIndex + 1 + index);
  }
  this.append(element);
  if (index < lastIndex) {
    this.children().eq(index).before(this.children().last());
  }
  return this;
}
```

Examples for the problem:

```
$("#controller").insertAt(0, "<div>first insert</div>");
$("#controller").insertAt(-1, "<div>append</div>");
$("#controller").insertAt(1, "<div>insert at second position</div>");
```

Here are some examples taken from my unittests:

```
$("<ul/>").insertAt(0, "<li>0</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(0, "<li>0</li>").insertAt(1, "<li>1</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(-1, "<li>-1</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(-1, "<li>-1</li>").insertAt(0, "<li>0</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(0, "<li>0</li>").insertAt(-1, "<li>-1</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(-1, "<li>-1</li>").insertAt(1, "<li>1</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(-1, "<li>-1</li>").insertAt(99, "<li>99</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(0, "<li>0</li>").insertAt(2, "<li>2</li>").insertAt(1, "<li>1</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(0, "<li>0</li>").insertAt(1, "<li>1</li>").insertAt(-1, "<li>-1</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(0, "<li>0</li>").insertAt(1, "<li>1</li>").insertAt(-2, "<li>-2</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(0, "<li>0</li>").insertAt(1, "<li>1</li>").insertAt(-3, "<li>-3</li>");
$("<ul/>").insertAt(0, "<li>0</li>").insertAt(1, "<li>1</li>").insertAt(-99, "<li>-99</li>");
```

**Edit:** It handles all negative indizes gracefully now.

Comment: great method! thanks for this. plugged it in and it worked like a charm.

Comment: var lastIndex = this.children().size(); doesn't work anymore - use this.children().length; instead.

Answer (score 11):

I found the listed solutions didn't work or were overly complicated. All you have to do is determine the direction you're appending from. Here is something simple written in an OOP manner for jQuery.

```
$.fn.insertIndex = function (i) {
    // The element we want to swap with
    var $target = this.parent().children().eq(i);

    // Determine the direction of the appended index so we know what side to place it on
    if (this.index() > i) {
        $target.before(this);
    } else {
        $target.after(this);
    }

    return this;
};
```

You can simply use the above with some simple syntax.

```
$('#myListItem').insertIndex(2);
```

Currently using this on a visual editor project moving tons of data around via drag and drop. Everything is working great.

---

Edit: I've added a live interactive CodePen demo where you can play with the above solution http://codepen.io/ashblue/full/ktwbe

Comment: I love the simplicity of your solution Ash – nice job. It's working well for me too.

Comment: I've updated the above example to include a CodePen demo http://codepen.io/ashblue/full/ktwbe

Comment: Isn't this just swapping elements around, without actually supporting inserting new ones?

Comment: @DarkNeuron You can insert and move as many elements around as you want. Check out the CodePen for an interactive demo.

Comment: This is more like `setIndex`: it moves existing elements around. This is not inserting an element at a specific index (eg, the parent may be empty).

Answer (score 8):

Use my simple plugin `Append With Index`  :

```
$.fn.appendToWithIndex=function(to,index){
        if(! to instanceof jQuery){
            to=$(to);
        };
        if(index===0){
            $(this).prependTo(to)
        }else{
            $(this).insertAfter(to.children().eq(index-1));
        }
    };*
```

Now :

```
$('<li>fgdf</li>').appendToWithIndex($('ul'),4)
```

Or :

```
$('<li>fgdf</li>').appendToWithIndex('ul',0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//jQuery plugin insertAtIndex included at bottom of post   

//usage:
$('#controller').insertAtIndex(index,'<div id="new">new</div>');

//original:
<div id="controller">
  <div id="first">1</div>
  <div id="second>2</div>
</div>

//example: use 0 or -int          
$('#controller').insertAtIndex(0,'<div id="new">new</div>');
  <div id="controller">
    <div id="new">new</div>
    <div id="first">1</div>
    <div id="second>2</div>
  </div>

//example: insert at any index     
$('#controller').insertAtIndex(1,'<div id="new">new</div>');
     <div id="controller">
        <div id="first">1</div>
        <div id="new">new</div>
        <div id="second>2</div>
     </div>

//example: handles out of range index by appending        
$('#controller').insertAtIndex(2,'<div id="new">new</div>');
      <div id="controller">
          <div id="first">1</div>
          <div id="second>2</div>
          <div id="new">new</div>
      </div>

/**!
 * jQuery insertAtIndex
 * project-site: https://github.com/oberlinkwebdev/jQuery.insertAtIndex
 * @author: Jesse Oberlin
 * @version 1.0
 * Copyright 2012, Jesse Oberlin
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
*/

(function ($) { 
$.fn.insertAtIndex = function(index,selector){
    var opts = $.extend({
        index: 0,
        selector: '<div/>'
    }, {index: index, selector: selector});
    return this.each(function() {
        var p = $(this);  
        var i = ($.isNumeric(opts.index) ? parseInt(opts.index) : 0);
        if(i <= 0)
            p.prepend(opts.selector);
        else if( i > p.children().length-1 )
            p.append(opts.selector);
        else
            p.children().eq(i).before(opts.selector);       
    });
};  
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.insertAfter()](https://api.jquery.com/insertafter/):

```
$('<div class="new">').insertAfter($('div.first'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this a lot, you can wrap it in a little function:

```
​var addit = function(n){
  $('#controller').append('<div id="temp">AAA</div>')
    .stop()
    .children('div:eq('+n+')')
    .before( $('#temp') );
} 

addit(2); // adds a new div at position 2 (zero-indexed)
addit(10); // new div always last if n greater than number of divs
addit(0); // new div is the only div if there are no child divs
```

If you're concerned about that temporary ID, you can add a final step to remove it.

**Edit:** Updated to handle cases of zero children, and specified *n* > current number of divs.

Comment: the problem would be if the `$('#controller')` doesn't have any children, then this function would not work... `addit(0)`

Comment: Reigel, that's true. For fun, I really wanted to try to avoid any (native) conditional. This updated one seems to work for the border cases.

Answer (score 0):

This one works best for me,

```
function SetElementIndex(element, index) {
            var Children = $(element).parent().children();
            var target = Children[index];

            if ($(element).index() > index) {
                if (target == null) {
                    target = Children[0];
                }
                if (target != element && target != null) {
                    $(target).before(element);
                }
            } else {
                if (target == null) {
                    target = Children[Children.length - 1];
                }
                if (target != element && target != null) {
                    $(target).after(element);
                }

            }
        };
```

Comment: Phil, can you please elaborate a little on your answer? Sometimes posting just code without an explanation just further adds to the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

You could always use prepend('#div');

ex.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#first').prepend('<div id="new">New</div>');

});​
```

That would put "#new" before "#first" Not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: That takes care of the 0th case.  What about the 2nd position?  He wants to be able to specify by number where to insert the div in the list o' divs