# Hook elements with insertAfter, but stay in parent - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to change certain elements' position dynamically. I found something that works here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593267/1419575 , but if the index number is higher than the children count, the element goes out of the parent.

Is there a way to make the child stay inside the parent element?

CSS

```
#hook-header {
    background: #dadada;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<header id="hook-header">
    <div id="ImTheFirstElement"><h1>This is the header hook</h1></div>
</header>

<div id="example-one">01</div>
<div id="example-nintynine">99</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example-one').appendTo('#hook-header');

    $.fn.appendToIndex=function(to,index){
        if(! to instanceof jQuery){
            to=$(to);
        };
        if(index===0){
            $(this).prependTo(to)
        }else{
            $(this).insertAfter(to.children().eq(index-1));
        }
    };
    $('#ImTheFirstElement').appendToIndex($('#hook-header'),0) 
    $('#example-one').appendToIndex($('#hook-header'),1)  
    $('#example-nintynine').appendToIndex($('#hook-header'),99)
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NicotineLL/V2JYs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the plugin to use the last element if `eq(index)` doesn't return an element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example-one').appendTo('#hook-header');

    $.fn.appendToIndex=function(to,index){
        if(! to instanceof jQuery){
            to=$(to);
        };
        if(index===0){
            $(this).prependTo(to)
        }else{
            var el = to.children().eq(index-1);
            el = el.length ? el : to.children().last();
            $(this).insertAfter(el);
        }
    };
    $('#ImTheFirstElement').appendToIndex($('#hook-header'),0) 
    $('#example-one').appendToIndex($('#hook-header'),1)  
    $('#example-nintynine').appendToIndex($('#hook-header'),99)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V2JYs/1/)

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm still learning how to do certain things in JS & jQuery so thank you for your help!