# Move the list item and restore it in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, list, append, bootstrap-4

the following code moves the list item as the last on a small screen width:

```
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).resize(myfunction);

function myfunction() {
    if (xs == true) {
        $('ul.page-nav-list').find('li.active').appendTo('ul.page-nav-list');
    } else {
        // how to get back to the original state
    }
}
```

**My question:** how to restore a list item to the original state for large resolutions?

I use the **Bootstrap 4 Breakpoint** plugin to detect the resolution.

Comment: Have a look at [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) before moving

Comment: Could you suggest how to modify this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```js
var orgIndex = 0;
$(function(){
  orgIndex=$('ul.page-nav-list').find('li.active').index();
  myFunction();
});
$(window).resize(myFunction);
xs=true;
function myFunction() {
  if (xs) {
    $('ul.page-nav-list').find('li.active').appendTo('ul.page-nav-list');
  } else {
    $('ul.page-nav-list').find('li.active').appendToWithIndex($('ul'),orgIndex)

  }
}
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593267/295783
$.fn.appendToWithIndex = function(to, index) {
  if (!to instanceof jQuery) {
    to = $(to);
  };
  if (index === 0) {
    $(this).prependTo(to)
  } else {
    $(this).insertAfter(to.children().eq(index - 1));
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="page-nav-list">
  <li class="active">Active</li>
  <li>Inactive</li>
  <li>Inactive</li>
  <li>Inactive</li>
</ul>
```