# How to insert a div in a specific position in another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html structure

```
<div class"parent1">
  <div class="child1">text</div>
  <div class="child2">text</div>
  <div class="child3">text</div>
  <div class="child4">text</div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child2">some text</div>
</div>
```

I am looping on the `parent1` div and getting the index of the child divs. And if a div with that class is not present in `parent2`, I want to add an empty div with that class and exactly in same position as in `parent1`. So the result would be like this

```
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2">some text</div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
  <div class="child4"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery code

```
$(".parent1 div").each(function(){
  let index = $(this).index();
  let css_class = $(this).attr("class");
  if ($("." + css_class).length < 1) {
    // Here I need that logic to insert an empty div in parent2 in same position as in parent1
  }
});
```

Comment: To simplify the logic, why don't you free up the `<div class="parent2"></div>` and then add all the elements from `parent1`?

Comment: Because, I want empty divs for the missing divs. While other divs contain content.

Answer (score 1):

I think this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3562533/11266880 explains how to insert a child at a certain index.. You can use it, if you iterate over your items with a for-loop instead of .each :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(".parent1 div").each(function() {
  let index = $(this).index();
  let css_class = $(this).attr("class");
  if ($(".parent2 ." + css_class).length < 1) {
    let div = "<div class=" + css_class + "></div>";
    if (index == 0) {
      $(".parent2").prepend(div);
    } else {
      $(".parent2 div:nth-child(" + index + ")").after(div);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
  <div class="child4"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child2">some text</div>
</div>
```

This is not much different from the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562493/jquery-insert-div-as-certain-index/3562533#3562533) that was already mentioned in the answer given by ehhc.